# Make a simple Java OptionPane Counter

Tags: java, button, window, counter, joptionpane

Hi I basically just want to make a JOptionPane window which has a number on top and 2 Buttons "+1" and "-1" if i press one of these Buttons the Number above should Decrease or Increase by 1. It would be very nice if someone could help me with posting a code or explaining how to make it to me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would just create a simple JDialog with 3 components, a JLabel and two JButtons. Add ActionListeners to each of the buttons to either add 1 or subtract one.

Start by reading the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). Maybe the section on `How to Use Buttons` and `How to Use Layout Managers`.

If you have problems then post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that shows what you have done.